# XAML style properties are not being inherited

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, .net-4.6

I made a simple style for the hyperlinks that target buttons:

```
<Style x:Key="Hyperlink" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ForegroundDarkBrush}" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <TextBlock x:Name="innerText" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource AppDarkBlueBrush}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="innerText" Property="TextDecorations" Value="Underline" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

My problem is that, when applied to the button control that has set some properties like `FontSize`, `FontWeight`, `FontFamily`, they are simply ignored and do not work:

```
<Button
    Command="{Binding OpenCommand}"
    Content="Open"
    FontSize="20"
    Style="{StaticResource Hyperlink}" />
```

How can I make a `TextBlock` in my style template inherit such properties?

## edit

Forgot my mention that properties like `FontSize` actually *do work* but only in the design mode.

Comment: Why aren't you just using a hyperlink?

Comment: @Andy I'd have to style it for my need anyways. I also doubt it would inherit these properties as well.

Comment: You usually put a hyperlink in a textblock and don't re template anything. So inheriting properties would be a bit academic and styling would be on the textblock. Which you seem to be trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can  indicate that you want your textblock to "inherit" some properties from the Button like this :

```
<Style x:Key="Hyperlink" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ForegroundDarkBrush}" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <TextBlock 
                  x:Name="innerText" 
                  Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                  FontSize={TemplateBinding FontSize}
                  FontWeight={TemplateBinding FontWeight}
                  FontFamily={TemplateBinding FontFamily}
                  />

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource     AppDarkBlueBrush}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="innerText" Property="TextDecorations" Value="Underline" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```